# Why the TypeError in the tempfile.py?

Tags: python

I'm importing the pltlib on Python3.7.5 by `from imview.lib import pltlib`.

Then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bowen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imview/lib/pltlib.py", line 15, in <module>
    cpt_rainbow = gmtColormap.get_rainbow()
  File "/home/bowen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imview/lib/gmtColormap.py", line 21, in get_rainbow
    fn = write_rainbow_cpt()
  File "/home/bowen/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imview/lib/gmtColormap.py", line 375, in write_rainbow_cpt
    N 255   0   0""")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 620, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I also check the source code here: github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tempfile.py
But it seems that my tempfile.py is correct, so why this error happen?

Comment: Probably an issue with imview.  Does it support the version of python your trying to use it with?  Maybe it only supports 2.7?

Comment: You're using an outdated version of `imview` - v0.2.0 matches the line numbers in your traceback, there's a v0.3.0 available.

Comment: This error looks like it is Python 2 code that is being run under Python 3.

Comment: But I checked the version of `imview` and it's already 0.3.0

Comment: OK the whole things work well on Python 2.7. So I guess @BoarGules is right.

Comment: `imview` hasn't been updated  for 3 years and PyPI carries no information about the version of Python it supports. In 2017 a substantial minority of the academic world was still teaching Python 2 and trying to ignore Python 3. The fact that the project documentation says nothing about the Python version it supports suggests that the author could not find the time and enthusiasm to migrate. Sad, but it happened to quite a few one-man projects.